# How to implement localization in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, localization, localizable.strings, react-localization

> We need to implement the localization in reactjs to define the string
>   value(s). How can I implement that?

One link is there https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-localization, but I am not getting the correct steps to add that.

I have tried by following steps:

1. I am adding my component in ES6:

```
    class Home extends React.Component
    {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
        render() {
            return (
              <Text>{strings.how}</Text>
             );
        }
    }
```

2. I have added the localization code as:-

```
    import LocalizedStrings from 'react-localization';
    let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
        en:{
            how:"How do you want your egg today?",
            boiledEgg:"Boiled egg",
            softBoiledEgg:"Soft-boiled egg",
            choice:"How to choose the egg"
        },
        it: {
            how:"Come vuoi il tuo uovo oggi?",
            boiledEgg:"Uovo sodo",
            softBoiledEgg:"Uovo alla coque",
            choice:"Come scegliere l'uovo"
        }
    });
```

> Now if you will see above :-  **{strings.how}** I should able
>   to get the strings value as it is defined in localization but I am not
>   able to do it.

Comment: I would suggest you change the accepted answer since the current one links to a completely different package.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> npm install react-localization

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-localization';

let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
  en:{
    how:"How do you want your egg today?",
    boiledEgg:"Boiled egg",
    softBoiledEgg:"Soft-boiled egg",
    choice:"How to choose the egg"
  },
  it: {
    how:"Come vuoi il tuo uovo oggi?",
    boiledEgg:"Uovo sodo",
    softBoiledEgg:"Uovo alla coque",
    choice:"Come scegliere l'uovo"
  }
 });

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      language: 'en'
    }
    
    this.handleLanguageChange = this.handleLanguageChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleLanguageChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let lang = e.target.value;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      language: lang
    }))
  }

  render() {
    strings.setLanguage(this.state.language);
    return (
      <div>
        Change Language: <select onChange={this.handleLanguageChange}>
          <option value="en">En- English</option>
          <option value="it">It- Italian</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        {strings.how}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

u can put your language specific data in a JSON file or or `.js` file. call that file in your current file and pass that object to `new LocalizedStrings()`.

Example:
**data.js**

```
const data = {
  en:{
    how:"How do you want your egg today?",
    boiledEgg:"Boiled egg",
    softBoiledEgg:"Soft-boiled egg",
    choice:"How to choose the egg"
  },
  it: {
    how:"Come vuoi il tuo uovo oggi?",
    boiledEgg:"Uovo sodo",
    softBoiledEgg:"Uovo alla coque",
    choice:"Come scegliere l'uovo"
  }
}
export {data};
```

in your current file import it as `import { data } from './data.js'`;
and then you can initialise as `let strings = new LocalizedStrings({data});`

You can read the detailed article here - [react-localization with hooks](https://www.ui-dev.in/2021/02/simplest-implementation-of-localization.html)

Check the working demo [Here](https://j32jr.csb.app/)

Comment: is this calling  `strings.setLanguage(this.state.language)` on the render function necessary ?

Comment: @btzr yes, it is necessary

Comment: Thanks  didn't see any examples or explanation of this on the docs ( readme file)

Comment: What if you want to use html tags inside messages? Example:
"<strong>Goodby> dear user"

Comment: this code can work only on one file...you cannot update language in one file and access to somewhere else

Answer (score 17):

Yahoo has created a package for implementing localization in React that might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl. It takes care of "dates, numbers, and strings, including pluralization and handling translations".

**Update 2021:** Here's the package now days:

- https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl

Comment: `react-localization` didn't seem to exist when I wrote my answer almost 3 years ago so I don't really see any point for downvoting this? Jees..

Comment: FYI: Keep downvoting this answer won't make it go away since SO shows the accepted answer at the top, @Gorakh Nath needs to change the accepted answer.

Comment: wait, how the heck did `react-localization` didn't exist at the time but the OP managed to mention it in the question itself? lol

Comment: btw, even the link is broken nowadays - it goes to some other package named format.js

Comment: The link works, it goes to the monorepo where react-intl lives. It's just a different organization now. The package was updated yesterday and has almost 1 million weekly downloads and 12k stats on GH. react-localization hasn't been updated in 2 years, has 36k weekly downloads and just 300 stars. But you do you.

Comment: Yeah `react-localization` existed in a 0.0.1 version. I just looked at the other answer (not the question) and somehow missed that `Published` on npm is when it was last updated and not first published. Life goes on.

Answer (score 4):

We use react-i18next. And then use [i18nexus](https://i18nexus.com) to auto-translate and manage translations.

Comment: I've used react-i18next and it seems like a pretty robust solution to providing localization on the front-end. It also seems to be well maintained as it seems to be updated pretty often and has a large number of weekly downloads on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-i18next).

Answer (score 0):

**first Add the dependencies**

```
npm install --save react-i18next i18next
```

If you are following along, start the app with npm start so you can give the two pages a look.

**Create the file structure**
In the src folder, create an i18n folder to hold all the information related to translating the app. Here’s the structure I used that is pretty common:

```
src
+-- i18n
    +-- locales
    |    +-- en
    |        +-- translations.json
    |    +-- es
    |        +-- translations.json
    +-- config.js
```

The config.js file contains the set up for the i18n instance. The two JSON files will hold the text that goes in the app. en for English and es for Spanish. If you are following along, create the file structure in the boilerplate.

**Configure the i18n instance**
The `i18n` instance will hold all of your translations, the current language, and other info and methods needed. You can configure it in the `config.js` file like this:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  lng: 'en',
  resources: {
    en: {
      translations: require('./locales/en/translations.json')
    },
    es: {
      translations: require('./locales/es/translations.json')
    }
  },
  ns: ['translations'],
  defaultNS: 'translations'
});

i18n.languages = ['en', 'es'];

export default i18n;
```

At the top, import the necessary dependencies. Next, the `use(initReactI18next)` will bind `react-i18next` to the `i18n` instance.

The first two properties of the init object parameter are a `fallback` language (`fallbackLng`) and default language (`lng`). I set both of these to English (`en`).

The `resources` are the JSON files with the translations that you created in the last step. The namespaces (`ns`) and default namespace (`defaultNS`) are the keys from the resources object.

You can split your translations into multiple files (namespaces) if you have a large app to simplify the files. In which case, you would add more than just the one file in the `resources` object and add it to the namespaces array. This app is small, so all the translations can go in one file.

**Add the i18n instance to your app**
In the `index.js` file of the boilerplate, which contains the entire app, import the `i18n` instance you created like this:

```
import './i18n/config';
```

Next, add an empty object `{}` to your two `translations.json` files so you don’t get any errors. You will fill in the keys later.

**Translate a functional component with the useTranslation hook**
The `Nav.js` file is the first component to translate. It’s a functional component, so you can use the `useTranslation` hook. Import it at the top with `import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'.`

Next, instead of using the implicit return with the component, add curly brackets and the return statement so you can declare a variable. Get the t function from the hook with `const { t } = useTranslation();`.

All together, it should look like something this:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const Nav = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    …
  );
}
```

The text you want to translate in this component is `Home` and `Page 2`. In your English `translations.json` file, add two properties to the object:

```
{
  "home": "Home",
  "page2": "Page 2"
}
```

Now, you can pass those keys to the t function to get the text. In the `Nav.js` component, use the t function to translate `Home` and `Page 2` to the English text like this: `t('key-from-json-file')`.

Here’s how those lines should look:

```
import { useTranslation } from ‘react-i18next;

const Nav = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  return (
    …

    <Link to="/">{t('home')}</Link>
    <Link to="/page2">{t('page2')}</Link>
  );
}
```

**Preview in Spanish**
The two nav buttons should be working for English. Add the same two keys to the Spanish JSON file so you can see what it will look like in Spanish. Here’s the translations:

```
{
  "home": "Casa",
  "page2": "Página 2"
}
```

After that, go to the config.js file, set the `lng` (default language) to `es` and reload the page. The nav links should show up in Spanish. When you are done, you can set the default language back to `en`.

**change languages with tab**

All the desired text should be available in both English and Spanish now. The last thing to do is to make it easy to switch between languages.

The `Footer.js` file has a few buttons and a changeLanguage function. Import the `useTranslation` hook from `react-i18next` at the top of the file. At the top of the Footer component, get the `i18n` instance from it like this: `const { i18n } = useTranslation();`.

Finally, in the changeLanguage function, use the `i18n.changeLanguage()` method, passing `e.target.value` to it, to change the langauge.

All together, it looks like this:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const Footer = () => {
  const { i18n } = useTranslation();

  function changeLanguage(e) {
    i18n.changeLanguage(e.target.value);
  }

  return(
    <div className='footer'>
      <button onClick={changeLanguage} value='en'>English</button>
      <button onClick={changeLanguage} value='es'>Español</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now, you should be able to switch languages by clicking the buttons on each page.

I found this article here. [:LINK:](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-localization-to-your-react-app/)