# Teams FX(Teams Toolkit) Localization

Tags: teams-toolkit

We have created a Teams Tab using Teams Toolkit. I would like to know how to implement localization in TeamsFX project. In SPFX we implemented this using localization files under "Loc" folder created by default. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

@Sai, thanks for your feedback. If you are asking how to Localize your app, you can follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-localization). If you are asking the localization of React content, you may find some useful information for this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741743/how-to-implement-localization-in-reactjs) since there are many different ways to localize React app.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check the links and let you know.

Comment: Hi Eric, 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-localization
I have looked in to this article which talks about localizing the app by creating JSON files for each language. But i do not see how to refer to these json files in my code. The example project mentioned in this article is using i18 module for transalation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks